# How to handle drop down list with div tag and multiple attributes?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, drop-down-menu

I am trying to automate the location selection process, however I am struggle with it.
So for, I can only open the menu and select the first item.
And my code is:

```
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
url = 'https://www.ebay.com/b/Food-Beverages/14308/bn_1642947?listingOnly=1&rt=nc'
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
button = driver.find_element_by_id('gh-shipto-click') //find the location button
button.click()
button2 = driver.find_element_by_id('gh-shipto-click-body-cnt') //open the menu
button2.click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@role='menuitemradio']").click() //choose the first location
```

I believe the attribute "data-makeup-index" (show in the pic) would help, but I don't know how to use it.

Sine some of you may not able to find the "ship to" button. Here is the html code I copied from the web.

```
<li id="gh-shipto-click" class="gh-eb-li">
<div class="gh-menu">
<button _sp="m570.l46241" title="Ship to" class="gh-eb-li-a gh-icon" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="gh-shipto-click-o" aria-label="Ship to Afghanistan"><i class="flgspr gh-flag-bg flaaf"></i><span>Ship to</span></button>
<i class="flgspr gh-flag-bg flaaf"></i>
```

[image]

[image]

[image: The "ship to" button html]

Comment: I didn't get it, what do you want to automate ? How could I open that div ?

Comment: @cruisepandey So I want to change the shipping location before the web scraping, and my question concerns how to choose different locations in the drop down menu.

Comment: Yes, can you help me with the manual steps ?

Comment: @cruisepandey 
Sure.
1. open url
2. click ship to on the right hand comer
3. open the menu bar
4. choose the location

Comment: I don't see `ship to on the right hand comer`, Do I need to login first ?

Comment: @cruisepandey
No, you don't need to login. Maybe you have already signed in? Maybe try to use incognito to open the url.

Comment: No luck,  Are you sure about this link https://www.ebay.com/b/Food-Beverages/14308/bn_1642947?listingOnly=1&rt=nc     - I see only one product, whereas in the screenshot I could see lot of them

Comment: @cruisepandey I added the picture.

Comment: @Nok just give the manual step to get the `Set your shipping location` pop

Comment: @YaDavMaNish
1. open url 2. click ship to on the right hand comer 3. open the menu bar 4. choose the location

Comment: May be I won't be able to help, since I don't see that option at all. Can you do this -> Press F12 in Chrome -> go to element section -> then right click on the element you want to share the outer HTML - > select copy and then outer HTML

Comment: @YaDavMaNish : I think that option is not available to us, it could be cause of our location

Comment: @cruisepandey
I have added it, thanks for you help anyways : )

Comment: I'd appreciate if that was in text format

Comment: @cruisepandey yes might be it is based on location

Comment: @Nok is it resolved, you got the fix?

Comment: @cruisepandey
I added part of the code, is it enough?

Comment: @YaDavMaNish
I added more information, is it sufficient?

Comment: can you let me know your current location country?

Comment: @YaDavMaNish Hong Kong

Comment: if you can give me that in text format here, I can try to make a replica of the same HTML

Comment: @Nok why I'm asking is, we are able to open the eBay site from a different country location

Comment: @cruisepandey
You want the page source?

Comment: yes that'd be helpful

Comment: Can I send you the text file?
It's too long to paste. Or you want me put it in serval parts here?

Comment: @Nok just put the specific part of it here, So it would be helpful

Comment: <li id="gh-shipto-click" class="gh-eb-li "><div class="gh-menu"><button _sp="m570.l46241" title="Ship to" class="gh-eb-li-a gh-icon" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="gh-shipto-click-o"><i class="flgspr flaemp"></i><span>Ship to</span></button><div class="gh-sublayer gh-modal__menu" id="gh-shipto-click-modal"><div id="gh-shipto-click-body"><div class="gh-shipto-click-body-cnt" id="gh-shipto-click-body-cnt"></div><div class="gh-throbber"><span class="gh-spinner"></span><span class="gh-state" tabindex="-1">

Comment: Loading...</span></div><section class="gh-status gh-status-attention" id="gh-shipto-click-body-status" aria-lablledby="gh-shipto-click-body-status_icon"><span id="gh-shipto-click-body-status_icon" class="gh-status-icon" aria-label="attention" role="img"></span><div class="status_cnt exit" tabindex="-1"><span>Error: Try Again</span><button class="gh-btn" id="gh-shipto-click-body-status-exit">Ok</button></div></section></div> </div><div id="gh-shipto-click-mask" class="gh-modal__mask"></div>

Comment: @YaDavMaNish@cruisepandey
Please check if it is useful~

Answer (score 1):

I have found my answer as below:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@role='menuitemradio'][{an integer}]").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the `Ship to` was not visible to my location, I've inspected it from different Geo location and guess what I was able to find this element`style="display: none;`
I've removed the none temporarily, and it got displayed.

`<li id="gh-shipto-click" class="gh-eb-li gh-modal-active" style="display:none;" aria-hidden="false">`

```
 You could find the element by these XPath and handle the dropdown

 #This XPath is taking you to the specific div where you need to provide the element index [1][2][3] the ID of this XPath is dynamic
 driver.find_element_by_xpath("((((//*[contains(@id,'nid-')])[2])//child::div/div")


 driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='cn']")
```

I know you got your solution, but this what I've tried It might help

[image]